# Any git hook to block merge conflict?

Tags: python, git, github, githooks, gitpython

I am planning to write a git hook in python to protect my github repository. It will detect merge conflict markers (like `>>>>>>`) and block the commit.

I have some initial ideas but it will be very helpful if I get similar hook samples. Advise about implementation from experienced people will be appreciated too.

Comment: What is the aversion to talking to the other contributor?  You're going to wind up talking to them *anyway* to discuss how to get past your inability (or their inability) to push.

Comment: It's always a good idea to have an automated filter process active. Also, might reduce some unwanted branch pull requests.

Comment: I fundamentally disagree.  Merge conflicts are the one area in which Git is pleading with you to intercede on its behalf.  What recourse should be taken shouldn't be up to a script to decide; it should be discussed between the committers and a consensus should be reached.  But that's my opinion.

Comment: I don't know, seems reasonable to me? I don't think he's trying to automatically resolve the conflict with the script, just stop the commit from happening.

Comment: @Makoto I think you're grossly misunderstanding the question. He wants to *"detect merge conflict markers ... and block the commit"*.  Nowhere is he indicating that he wants the git hook to take any action. In fact, if you actually think about it, he's in agreement with you that the merge conflicts need to be dealt with. He's admirably trying to ensure that none ever go missed during a merge.